# Getting IIS redirects proper for second HTTP site

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, exchange-2010

2x IIS sites on one host.
I have mainsite.domain.com and secondsite.seconddomain.com. Both sites point to the same IP in public DNS.
Nothing wrong with mainsite.domain.com, it redirects and goes to its own HTTPS site without issue.

Going to secondsite.seconddomain.com without HTTPS, it re-directs me to the HTTPS mainsite.domain.com when I want it to go to its own secured site. It's odd that HTTPS secondsite.seconddomain.com still works as expected.

Is there anyway to make HTTP of secondsite.seconddomain.com redirect to its own HTTPS entry?

Answer (score 0):

check your bindings and host headers on the sites they will both need bindings for port 80 and 443 both bindings will need host headers for the respective site.  it sounds like passably your port 80 traffic is only making it to the one site.